# Python Package Deployed to AWS Lambda contains parent folder name

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I created a python package in PyCharm and this is the folder structure

[image]

I am trying to deploy this to AWS Lambda using Cloud Formation Template , and using the below one. The code.zip is placed in the S3 bucket from where it will be fetched during deployment.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Lambda function
Resources:
  Function:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: code
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Role: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/lambdaExecutionRole11030037
      Code:
        S3Bucket: apicode11
        S3Key: code.zip
      Runtime: python3.8
      Timeout: 15
```

After it is deployed successfully in Lambda the folder structure of the code is getting changed and the parent folder name is getting appended to all the files

[image]

Please help me out to understand if any change is needed in the Code structure or CFT so that parent folder name is not appended in Lambda

Comment: How did you create the `code.zip`?

Comment: @jellycsc the code.zip was created using power shell 'Compress-Archive code code.zip' and also created it normally in windows i.e. right click Compressed

Answer (score 0):

You can specify path in your handler:

```
Handler: code/index.lambda_handler
```

Comment: This works but it is more like a workaround, as and when the complexity of the code will increase it will be difficult to maintain.

Comment: @ArijitDas Its not a workaround. This is how it is done. You are using non-default handler, so you specify it. Why would that be a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The ZIP file should not have any folder. All you need to keep the module at the root location.

You folder structure should be like 
[image]

You can create a zip file by using -

```
cd message-retry
zip ../message-retry.zip *
```

Comment: I am working from a windows system, even if I keep the module at root location while uploading it I will need to create a .zip archive and when this zip is getting deployed using cft then the name of the archived folder is getting appended

Comment: That means your zip file contains one root folder as `code`.
You should just keep `index.py` in your `code` folder. You should not add `__init__.py`. If it has code then you must move it to `index.py`. I will suggest you to follow [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package-create.html#python-package-create-no-dependency).

Comment: Once, zip created you can verify by opening the zip file and you should see the `index.py` module. Not, any other folder or file.

Comment: i have gone through this earlier, this works only when a single .py file is to be deployed, but the issue i am facing is when i am trying to do a package deployment.